# Spring Integration - Custom JMSCorrelationId using jms:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Is it possible to pass a custom JMSCorrelationId while using  ?

I want to do this because the consumer system of my messages sets back a payload property as the JMSCorrelationId.

I checked JMSOutboundGateway.java for the same but it seems it ie either use JMSmessageId or generated unique id as JMSCorrelationId to map the incoming messsages.

Any help ?

UPDATE

I am able to set using header-enricher receving input on input channel and this enriched header ouput is received by jms outbound gateway. But i saw the code in JMSOutboundGateway it creates the selector with JMSMessageID because of which i am not able to receive the message.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
            <int:header name="jms_correlationId" value="12345"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with `4.0.1` the `<int-jms:outbound-gateway correlation-key>` supports `JMSCorrelationID*` token to reuse an existing `correlationId` from request message:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3405

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jms.html#d4e8792